# Is anything elided in the sentence?

Tags: relative-pronouns

The original sentence:

> In our day fish are caught in the sea and brought to us by rail and
>   lorry; only the angler still thinks fresh-water fish important, and
>   pollution of rivers drives him into smaller and smaller reaches **in
>   which** to practise his sport.

My question is on "**in which**." Is "**which**" a relative pronoun here? Is it an elided version of something like below? Or it suffices itself?

> In our day fish are caught in the sea and brought to us by rail and
>   lorry; only the angler still thinks fresh-water fish important, and
>   pollution of rivers drives him into smaller and smaller reaches in
>   which **[he is able]** to practise his sport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In which to X" is a common phrase meaning "places to do X" It may mean specifically "places where one is able to do X" or "places where one chooses to do X".The3 words  "in which" can also refer to something that is not a place. In this construction, "which" is a relative pronoun, fronted by "in". Inn this construction "to X" is, or contains, the verb of the subordinate clause introduced by the relative pronoun which. In the example the antecedent of "which" is "reaches" or perhaps "smaller and smaller reaches".

While the form "in which he is able to" could be used in the example from the question, the original example need not be thought of as an elided form.

Here are several examples. In some "which" refers to a place, in others it does not.

> - We looked for a chemical in which to dissolve the powder.
> - This is my prize orchid, in which I take great pride.
> - This is the new sports stadium, in which home games are played.
> - This is a study room, in which one may find quiet.
> - Wild animals need undisturbed areas in which to live.
> - This is an excellent restaurant in which to find Italian food.
> - This is a reference book in which you may place your trust.